# Widget like facebook messenger in home screen

Tags: java, android, android-widget, homescreen

hi I want create a widget for my app like facebook messenger

[image]

But I do not know how to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are looking out for this
http://blog.gbinghan.com/2013/08/android-chathead-tutorial-1-setup.html
http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/05/facebook-chat-heads-feature.html

for ios 
https://github.com/brutella/chatheads

Comment: tanks for your answer :)